# Obtener el valor devuelto de un subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, servicio, observable

Estoy usando una Apirest y he configurado un archivo .service en Angular con Observables.

Necesito obtener el valor que devuelve el subscribe para poder después devolverlo con un return pero siempre me lanza el return antes de termine el http.service

```
getIdMyDirector(centroMiDirector): number {

this.userService.getIdMiDirector("miDirector", centroMiDirector).subscribe(
      idDirectorHttp =>  { this.idDirector = idDirectorHttp; }
      );

    return this.idDirector;
}
```

Comment: Que quieres hacer con ese idDirector?

Comment: Aqui te explica como https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605311/2400373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta podría variar dependiendo de que quieras hacer.

Si es por ejemplo método que esta directamente en el TS del componente en el que estas trabajando y la variable la vas a utilizar para mostrar idDirector en el HTML podrías solo eliminar el return.

```
getIdMyDirector(centroMiDirector) {
  this.userService.getIdMiDirector("miDirector", centroMiDirector)
  .subscribe(
    idDirectorHttp => {this.idDirector = idDirectorHttp}
    );
}
```

En caso de ser usado para hacer algún otro proceso con el idDirector te recomiendo usar Async - Await.

```
async getAsyncData() {
  this.asyncResult = await this.httpClient.get<Employee>(this.url).toPromise();
  console.log('No issues, I will wait until promise is resolved..');
}
```

[Mas informacíon de como usar Async y Await](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)

Comment: Finalmente he convertido el httpService a promer y con el .then() recupero el valor que necesito, también uso el async-await para que se espere a que termine el httpService. Es la mejor manera que encontrado

Answer (score 0):

Las operaciones en javascript o typescript no se hacen de forma secuencial,
por lo tanto, debes hacer el return dentro del suscribe.

```
getIdMyDirector(centroMiDirector): number {
    this.userService.getIdMiDirector("miDirector", centroMiDirector).subscribe(
      idDirectorHttp =>  {
         this.idDirector = idDirectorHttp; 
         return this.idDirector;
    });
}
```